# Adapter overwrite the values of 5th row and so on

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Why Adapter overwrites the value of `seekbar`, all values are set normally but when 5 item value set it will replace the next item value( firstly value is set normal on the item row but after few millisecond values replace with next item).

1:-want to set all values on its normal positions.

2:-reason why value replaces after few milliseconds.

```
extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GuaranteeAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private RangeSeekBar mRangeSeekBarPrice;
ArrayList<int[]> listOfGuarantees1 = new ArrayList<int[]>();
int[] values;
int tripsCompleted;
public static int[] diversvalues;
private List<ModelWeeklyGuarantee> GauranteeList;
Context context;
public ArrayList<Integer> weklyGuarantees = new ArrayList<Integer>();
JSONArray jsonArray;
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView year, serverMessage, completeRides, incompleteRides;
    public LinearLayout MainLL;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
        serverMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.messagefromserver);
        completeRides = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_complete_ride);
        incompleteRides = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_left_rides);
        mRangeSeekBarPrice = (RangeSeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.range_seek_bar_price);
        MainLL = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
//These txt view values are placed on its normal positions
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {


    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

public GuaranteeAdapter(List<ModelWeeklyGuarantee> GauranteeList, Context context) {
    this.GauranteeList = GauranteeList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.guarantee_list_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ModelWeeklyGuarantee ModelGuarantee = GauranteeList.get(position);

    this.tripsCompleted = ModelGuarantee.tripsCompleted;
    holder.year.setText(ModelGuarantee.getDate());
    holder.completeRides.setText(String.valueOf(ModelGuarantee.getTripsCompleted()));
    holder.incompleteRides.setText(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(ModelGuarantee.getTripsLeft())));
  holder.serverMessage.setText(String.valueOf(ModelGuarantee.getWeeklyDataList()));
     jsonArray = ModelGuarantee.getWeeklyDataList();
    Log.d("getWeeklyDataList", "" + jsonArray);
    weklyGuarantees = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        weklyGuarantees.clear();
    for (int i = 0, count = jsonArray.length(); i < count; i++) {
        try {
            weklyGuarantees.add(i, Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(jsonArray.get(i).toString())));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (weklyGuarantees.size() > 0) {
        diversvalues = null;
        diversvalues = new int[Collections.max(weklyGuarantees) + 1];
        Log.d("weklyGuaranteesss", "" + weklyGuarantees);
        for (int i = 0; i <= Collections.max(weklyGuarantees); i++) {
            try {
                diversvalues[i] = i;
                //i++;
                Log.d("ivalue", "" + i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        Log.d("devider", "" + diversvalues.toString());
        mRangeSeekBarPrice.setAdapter(new DemoRangeAdapter11(1,Collections.max(weklyGuarantees) + 1,diversvalues,position));
    }

    Log.d("posa ", " " + position);
    mRangeSeekBarPrice.setSelectedMinValue(ModelGuarantee.tripsCompleted + 1);
    mRangeSeekBarPrice.setDailyarrayListValues(weklyGuarantees);
    mRangeSeekBarPrice.setbothtripscompleted(tripsCompleted);
    Log.d("callednow", " va    " + weklyGuarantees);
    mRangeSeekBarPrice.setbothtripscompleted(tripsCompleted);
    mRangeSeekBarPrice.setNotifyWhileDragging(true);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return GauranteeList.size();
}
```

Comment: Put `private RangeSeekBar mRangeSeekBarPrice;` indide `ViewHolder` class . Second think you need to save the previous state of each item otherwise it will reset during scroll .

Comment: @ADM thanks for humble reply i will try and ask you again, again thanks brother i will try it for 5 days

Comment: Yeah try it . If you face any problem then add a screen shot of your list screen in question  this will make it more clear .

Comment: Thanks brother you are genius post it as answer

Comment: Is it working fine now ?

Comment: brother how i will Second think you need to save the previous state of each item otherwise it will reset during scrol
but in this time it will not reset the values

Comment: All working fine but how
 Second think you need to save the previous state of each item otherwise it will reset during scrol

Comment: Test it yourself . Its the RecycleView's behavior ite out of boundary will be recycler and reload during scroll . I am not aware of your List right now.

Comment: ok brother again thanks for this huge help